# Put submission from input field into SQL query after LIKE

Tags: html, sql, input, sql-like

How can I access the value the user submits in the input field at the top and place it in the code after "LIKE" in the SQL query? My code works with the given value, 9999, but I want that value to instead be whatever the user enters into the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter Tracking Code: <input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Submit">

<table id="switch-hitters" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.0.1/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>

<script>

var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_1elTo5zH1ew6KPYwoWtixX9hzFc8oxdRy5A0LWFkwg/edit#gid=0';
$('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like 9999"
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter Tracking Code: <input type="text" id="textbox_id">
<input type="button" value="Submit">

<table id="switch-hitters" class="table table-condensed table-striped"</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.0.1/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>

<script>

var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_1elTo5zH1ew6KPYwoWtixX9hzFc8oxdRy5A0LWFkwg/edit#gid=0';
var elem =  document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
$('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like "+elem
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from the input textbox you can either use the following:

Get value from text box based on its **id** which you need to set in your code:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" >
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

OR

Get value of the first textbox in the HTML document if you don't want to set an id :

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

Then in your script :

```
var elem =  document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
$('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like "+elem
});
```

Comment: This isn't working -- I posted the updated code above

Comment: @Nate is the query not working or is the value not being fetched from the textbox. Use console.log(elem) to check.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the browser: Error: Unexpected API response format.
osheetrock.min.js:6:1480
usheetrock.min.js:6:5899
(anonymous function)

Comment: It has something to do with the Sheetrock library I'm using. http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/